# Running two scripts in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, background

Dear people of the internet, I need some help...
I have a Python script, `main.py` in which a user can enter 2 variables
First, `ReminderTime` is an int, second, `ReminderText` is a string. I want to send the two variables to another Python script, `reminder.py`.
The reminder script will do stuff with the two objects, and then it will use `ToastNotifier` to make a Windows notification, before shutting down.
The main script will still run in the foreground during that time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

Simple example:

```
p = Process(target=f, args=(ReminderTime, ReminderText))
p.start()
```

`f` - is function in your `reminder.py` that will start that script (like `main` in `main.py` by default)
`args` - is all arguments you need to send to this function

Also, you need to import you function `import reminder.function_name`

This code will start you `f` function in background, so main code will still runing.

Comment: It doesn't quite work, the reminder.py script doesn't run at all

Comment: @VukBajić, Can you show me your code?
Use https://pastebin.com/ or equivalent.